# How to redirect to another url when i have frames set

Tags: php, url, frame

I have an index.php file which has frameset. My problem is how to redirect to homepage.php?

I tried already header("Location: homepage.php"); it works for me but it only showed on the

frame I set. I want to show it in full window.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since PHP is a server side language, it can only affect how a request is handled. There are two main methods you can use to do what you want. Which method you will want to use depends on how your user is interacting with your site.

Method 1: Use `target="_top"` or `target="_parent"` on a link.

`<a href="homepage.php" target="_parent" />`

Method 2: Use JavaScript to redirect the top window to the page you want.

`window.top.location.href = "homepage.php";`

Comment: should i use header()?

Comment: I tried it but the frame just clear. the homepage.php doesn't show

Comment: header() will only work if you're wanting to redirect an already active request. What exactly is your purpose for wanting to redirect the user?

Comment: Yeah, i want to rediredt the user to the homepage.php

Comment: Yes, but is this redirection occurring in response to them logging in, clicking a link, or because of some other reason?

Comment: Or should i make a link to the redirection page?

Comment: Like I've said a few times now, that depends on why you're redirecting the user. If the user clicks a link inside your frameset, and you want that to redirect the entire window, just add `target="_top"` to the link. If you're wanting to redirect using something similar to header due to a successful login, you'll want to use the javascript solution instead.